Why does ram memory increase in idle stage?
I am deployed a milvus-standalond in docker.
Issue is i do nothing in milvus still milvus use cpu 5 to 6% continuously and ram is consumed continuously like reach 300 mb to 390 mb in duration of half hour.
Language is python
Milvus version 2.4.6
Code is write from (write very basic code from)
https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/examples/vector_stores/MilvusIndexDemo/
Please help why milvus not release ram in idle stage.

I just installed a standalone program on my computer and waited 30 minutes. While memory gradually increases to 120MB in the half-hour, CPU usage is only about 5% of total.
To print the performance report, use the pprof tool and the following two commands:
curl http://127.0.0.1:9091/debug/pprof/heap > heap_snapshot.heap

go tool pprof -png heap_snapshot.heap

A PNG file will be produced by the tool. When we open the PNG file, we can see how the CPU and memory resources are used. The standalone has a few task loops for sending time ticks, checking garbage collection, checking compaction, etc. Also, there are grpc connections between nodes that require upkeep. I don't think it is a problem.
result
